# Dplyr's mutate function: add column with value, based on filtration of another column

Tags: r, dplyr

Assume we have pseudo table like following:

```
library(dplyr)

test_df = tibble(rank = c(1,2,3,4,5), x = c(10,20,30,40,50))
test_df

# A tibble: 5 x 2
   rank     x
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10
2     2    20
3     3    30
4     4    40
5     5    50
```

What I want to achieve is to add a new column which would contain the same value for all records,
but this value should be taken from 'x' clolumn base on filtration of 'rnk' column.
For instance I need to add column 'y' based on 'x' where 'rnk' == 3, so the output should be following:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
   rank     x     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10    30
2     2    20    30
3     3    30    30
4     4    40    30
5     5    50    30
```

Just curios how it could be achieved using mutate() function?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
test_df %>% mutate(y = x[rank == 3])
# A tibble: 5 x 3
   rank     x     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10    30
2     2    20    30
3     3    30    30
4     4    40    30
5     5    50    30
```

Comment: Thank you for this elegant approach, it works great! But tell me please, how construction x[rnk == 3] could apply to rnk vector when x is the seperate vector, not a data.frame?

Comment: @KarmaOfJesus, if `x` is a separate vector, then you can only select based on values of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match` -

```
library(dplyr)

test_df %>% mutate(y = x[match(3, rank)])

#   rank     x     y
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    10    30
#2     2    20    30
#3     3    30    30
#4     4    40    30
#5     5    50    30
```

If there are multiple values of 3, `match` would return the first value of `x`.

If there is no 3 in the data `match` would return `NA`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test_df)[, y := x[which(rank == 3)[1]]]
```